# Select default option with ngValue in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, html-select, default

I've read many posts about this topic but I still don't understand what is going on in this code.

I'm trying to select a default value (component.html):

```html
    <select class="custom-select" formControlName="country">
          <option *ngFor="let country of countries$ | async" [ngValue]="country.myCode">{{ country.name }}</option>
        </select>
```

`countries$` leads to an `Query.select('countries')`

This leads to an interface:

```js
   export interface AppState {
     countries?: Country[];
   }
```

And the array Country:

```js
    export interface Country {
      id: number;
      name: string;
      myCode: string;
    }
```

I tried to solve it with `[(ngModel)]="countries$"` but it didn't work. I also tried to kick out `ngValue` to use `[value]` but every country includes provinces, which disappear after I kicked out `ngValue`.

Don't know what else to do, please help. Thank you

Comment: You could use the `selected` input of the `option` tag like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observable-async-binding)

Comment: Thanks, but the default value should be selected from the beginning

Comment: What is `from the beginning`? Should there be a value before the observable finishes?

Comment: @MikeS. I mean the default value should be visible the whole time. Without clicking on a button. It is just a select input field

Comment: The button is there to fake an observable, the value will automatically be selected once it finishes, no matter where from